# TensorFlow dynamic_rnn input for regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I'm stuck trying to convert an existing tensorflow sequence to sequence classifier to a regressor.

Currently I'm stuck in handling the input for `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`. According to the documentation and other answers, input should be in the shape of `(batch_size, sequence_length, input_size)`. However my input data has only two dimensions: `(sequence_length, batch_size)`.

The original solution uses `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` as an intermediate step before feeding input to `dynamic_rnn()`. If I understand correctly, I believe I don't need this step since I'm working on a regression problem, not a classification problem.

Do I need the embedding_lookup step? If so, why? If not, how can I fit my `encoder_inputs` directly into `dynamic_rnn()`?

Below is a working minimalized example of the general idea:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

PAD = 0
EOS = 1
VOCAB_SIZE = 10 # Don't think I should need this for regression?
input_embedding_size = 20

encoder_hidden_units = 20
decoder_hidden_units = encoder_hidden_units

LENGTH_MIN = 3
LENGTH_MAX = 8
VOCAB_LOWER = 2
VOCAB_UPPER = VOCAB_SIZE
BATCH_SIZE = 10

def get_random_sequences():
    sequences = []
    for j in range(BATCH_SIZE):
        random_numbers = np.random.randint(3, 10, size=8)
        sequences.append(random_numbers)
    sequences = np.asarray(sequences).T
    return(sequences)

def next_feed():
    batch = get_random_sequences()

    encoder_inputs_ = batch
    eos = np.ones(BATCH_SIZE)
    decoder_targets_ = np.hstack((batch.T, np.atleast_2d(eos).T)).T
    decoder_inputs_ = np.hstack((np.atleast_2d(eos).T, batch.T)).T

    #print(encoder_inputs_)
    #print(decoder_inputs_)

    return {
        encoder_inputs: encoder_inputs_,
        decoder_inputs: decoder_inputs_,
        decoder_targets: decoder_targets_,
    }

### "MAIN"

# Placeholders
encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(LENGTH_MAX, BATCH_SIZE), dtype=tf.int32, name='encoder_inputs')
decoder_targets = tf.placeholder(shape=(LENGTH_MAX + 1, BATCH_SIZE), dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_targets')
decoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(LENGTH_MAX + 1, BATCH_SIZE), dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_inputs')

# Don't think I should need this for regression problems
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([VOCAB_SIZE, input_embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0), dtype=tf.float32)
encoder_inputs_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, encoder_inputs)
decoder_inputs_embedded = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, decoder_inputs)

# Encoder RNN
encoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(encoder_hidden_units)
encoder_outputs, encoder_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    encoder_cell, encoder_inputs_embedded, # Throws 'ValueError: Shape (8, 10) must have rank at least 3' if encoder_inputs is used
    dtype=tf.float32, time_major=True,
)

# Decoder RNN
decoder_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(decoder_hidden_units)
decoder_outputs, decoder_final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    decoder_cell, decoder_inputs_embedded, 
    initial_state=encoder_final_state,
    dtype=tf.float32, time_major=True, scope="plain_decoder",
)
decoder_logits = tf.contrib.layers.linear(decoder_outputs, VOCAB_SIZE)
decoder_prediction = tf.argmax(decoder_logits, 2)

# Loss function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(decoder_logits, tf.one_hot(decoder_targets, depth=VOCAB_SIZE, dtype=tf.float32)))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)


sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

max_batches = 5000
batches_in_epoch = 500

print('Starting train')
try:
    for batch in range(max_batches):
        feed = next_feed()
        _, l = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed)

        if batch == 0 or batch % batches_in_epoch == 0:
            print('batch {}'.format(batch))
            print('  minibatch loss: {}'.format(sess.run(loss, feed)))
            predict_ = sess.run(decoder_prediction, feed)
            for i, (inp, pred) in enumerate(zip(feed[encoder_inputs].T, predict_.T)):
                print('  sample {}:'.format(i + 1))
                print('    input     > {}'.format(inp))
                print('    predicted > {}'.format(pred))
                if i >= 2:
                    break
            print()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('training interrupted')
```

I have read similar questions here on stackoverflow but find my self still puzzled as to how to solve this.

EDIT:
I think I should clarify that the code above works well, however the real desired output should mimic a noisy signal (text to speech for example) which is why I think I need continuous output values instead of words or letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do continuous why can't you just reshape your input placeholders to be of shape `[BATCH, TIME_STEPS, 1]` and add that one extra dimension into your input via `tf.expand_dims(input, 2)`. This way, your input would match the dimensions that `dynamic_rnn` expects (actually in your case, since you are doing `time_major=True` your input should be of shape `[TIME_STEPS, BATCH, 1])`

I'd be curious to know how you'd then handle the switch of the output dimension from your cell size to 1. Right now you have this line:

```
decoder_logits = tf.contrib.layers.linear(decoder_outputs, VOCAB_SIZE)
```

But since you are no longer doing a classification, then `VOCAB_SIZE` is just 1? I asked a similar question here a few days ago, but didn't get any responses. I'm doing it this way (using 1), but not sure whether it's appropriate (seems to sort-of work in practice, but not perfectly).

Comment: Great! It seems to be working, didn't realise simply adding a dimension like that would do the trick. Good point about the switch to the output dimension, hadn't even thought about that yet. Setting `VOCAB_SIZE` to 1 seems to indeed do the trick.